# create-react-app markdown-loader for webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I've cloned the create-react-app and I would like to use the webpack plugin markdown-loader. Can someone please advise me how I would modify the webpack.config.dev.js to do so.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to eject out of create-react-app, it's actually fairly simple to do with loader directives.

1. Install `markdown-loader` to turn the markdown into HTML
2. Install `html-loader` to be able to load HTML into JS

Then:

```
import YourMarkdown from '!html-loader!markdown-loader!./YOURFILE.md'

export default function MarkdownComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: YourMarkdown }} />
}
```

Comment: After taking this approach with create-react-app, I hit this error:
ERROR in src\views\RevisedLayout.jsx
  Line 31:1:  Unexpected '!' in '!html-loader!./revised-layout.html'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

I was able to wrokaround that by including:
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */

(as per this answer)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443274/webpack-2-expected-error-using-with-import

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Dan Abramovs' post here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

> All the build settings are preconfigured and can’t be changed.

If you wish to modify any of the settings you can `Eject` from the app.

> “Ejecting” lets you leave the comfort of Create React App setup at any time. You run a single command, and all the build dependencies, configs, and scripts are moved right into your project. At this point you can customize everything you want, but effectively you are forking our configuration and going your own way.

`npm run eject` will cause all the config options to be moved over to your application giving you full control over the config. - ***This is a one way process.***

Comment: Hi Gerraint, I should of said that I have already ejected from the app. Its more a question of how do I implement using markdown templating with react and webpack?