# webpack 2 expected '!' error using with import

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack

I want to use this svg loader, https://github.com/jhamlet/svg-react-loader

in the instruction I followed the usage, like

```
import Logo from 'svg-react-loader?name=Logo!../images/logo.svg';
```

But I got error

```
Line 3:  Unexpected '!' in 'svg-react-loader?name=Logo!../images/logo.svg'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
```

Comment: what version are you using ??

Comment: please provide your `webpack.config` ^^

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is not an error from webpack, but from ESLint, specifically from [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import).

Using [inline loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline) is generally not recommended and the ESLint rule [import/no-webpack-loader-syntax](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-webpack-loader-syntax.md) exists to warn you from doing this. If you do want to use inline loaders and don't want ESLint to complain, you can disable the rule in your `.eslintrc`.

```
"rules": {
  "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": "off"
}
```

Or you can disable the rule just for that specific import, if you want to be warned about inline loaders, except for this one, because you might need it in this particular case.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import Logo from 'svg-react-loader?name=Logo!../images/logo.svg';
```

Comment: Note for others - the comment line in the second form is important too :)

Answer (score 4):

easier and safer solution is to add the following line to the file where you want to use the inline loaders:

```
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
```

this will switch this option only for the file that includes this line.